# How to find order/lag of a GARCH model by R？ (build GARCH model)

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to fit the GARCH model, and I found the mean equation by now, but have no idea about the next step. That is fit the volatility part.
I think I should first find the lag and then find the coefficients.
Many used GARCH(1,1) but didn't explain why. Maybe if anyone can give a step by step example to build GARCH model？

Here is what I have done.

1.simulate a time series

```
library(fGarch)
set.seed(1234)
r_t<- garchSim(garchSpec(model = list(mu=0.01,ar=c(0.03,-0.03),
     alpha= 0.12, beta= 0.09, omega= 0.01)),n = 200)
ts.plot(r_t)
```

2.Fit the mean function, and found it is

0.6232*r(t-1) -0.6027*r(t-2)+ 0.7834*r(t-3)         -0.5700*a(t-1)+ 0.4637*a(t-2)-0.8937*a(t-3) +0.1228965

```
a=matrix(0,nrow=6,ncol=6)
rownames(a)<-0:5
colnames(a)<-0:5
for(i in 0:5)
{
  for(j in 0:5)
  {
   a[i+1,j+1]=arima(r_t,order=c(i,0,j))$aic
  }
}
arima(r_t,order=c(3,0,3))
intercept=(0.0241/(1-0.6232-(-0.6027)-0.7834))
```

3. Next, I should model volatility like this？ and then？
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diyco.png)

> ```
> set.seed(1234)
> mu<-arima.sim(model=list(order=c(3,0,3),
>              ar=c(0.6232,-0.6027,0.7834),
>              ma=c(-0.5700,0.4637,-0.8937)),n=200)+0.1228965
> at<-r_t-mu
> set.seed(1234)
> sigma2<-(at/rnorm(200))^2
> ```